# Which monitor should I buy?

Tags: monitors

I want to buy a monitor and I'm not sure which one I should buy. I have those two in my short list:

- BenQ GL2450H
- Asus VS247HR

Now, both seem to be fine for my purpose, but there still is a difference in the price. Can anybody find some great differences or can advise me one of them?

I'm particularly interested in a very good view angle and a high refresh rate (max. 5ms).

Comment: Do you have any particular criteria you're judging by?  For example, viewing angle, color quality, or refresh rate?

Comment: @Mark for me, it's important to have a very good view angle, a high refresh rate (max. 5s), and that it's 24" big... colors should also not be too bad...

Comment: I've edited your post to include your requirements.  On paper, neither of your monitors is likely to meet the "view angle" requirement: they both use TN technology, which tends to have severe color shifts as you view them from off-axis.

Answer (score 2):

I am using 2 of the BenQ GL2450H(T) and I am very satisfied with them, 60 Hertz is enough for every game and with 24 Inches you can see clearly everything. It(Mine) has a HDMI-Input, DVI and VGA.

I would definitely recommand this one. I have never heard of the other one though so I can't tell anything about it.